How to records changecount in cells of another column e.g to record change in a1 to b1, a2 to b2, a3 to b3 and so on ? thanx in advance
In one column, cells have been changing due to data feeding from website. How to records changecount in cells of another column
How to records changecount in cells of another column e.g to record change in a1 to b1, a2 to b2, a3 to b3 and so on ? thanx in advance

The code for this is very simple:
  If Target.Column = 1 Then ' Only to be applicable for first column ("A:A")
    Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Target.Offset(0, 1).Value + 1
  End If

The whole question is:

Do you need this code to run on your entire workbook (all sheets)?
Or do you need this code only to run for a specific worksheet?

Hereby a screenshot on how it looks for the entire workbook (I've added the code for the single worksheet but I've put the code in comment):

In case you don't know which event you need, you might add all of them and add a breakpoint at the beginning, so you might learn which one is fired when an update happens:


Specific sheet, Sir

@ParveenKumar: You're welcome. In case my answer is useful and/or solves your question, thanks for upvoting and/or accepting it, this is how this site works.

Ofcourse @Dominique
the above vba is working fine when we entered the data manually, but it's not working when the data is streamed through website

@ParveenKumar: I don't know which event you need, you might do some experimenting as I explained in my edit.

Sir, I tried with every options, manually it's working but not working with data which is being continuously received in excel cells through website

@ParveenKumar: in case you are using an Excel query, you might check this site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.querytable.beforerefresh

data is being received using python scripts through website api not though excel query
